# Android, How to use microphone in order to calculate sound frequencies?

Tags: android, microphone, audio

I'm working on Audio tuner application in order to tune musical instruments.
User should play a note, then in my application I should show which frequency it has.

The first, I should access to microphone?

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
```

Then I need to calculate frequency of sound. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also trying to do this. I haven't managed it myself yet, as I'm completely new to android development, but here are two useful links to the source code of other tuners, one in Java, one not:

- http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/01/17/a-5k-java-guitar-tuner/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32172/FFT-Guitar-Tuner

EDIT:
Thought I better link to the MANY alternatives on this site with people trying to make a guitar tuner.

- [How to create tuner that runs continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325656/how-to-create-tuner-that-runs-continuously)
- [Sound convertion to frequency in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928695/sound-convertion-to-frequency-in-android)
- [Real time pitch detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354084/real-time-pitch-detection)

RE-EDIT:
[FFT.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html)

Solved my problems. (Not linked properly because I'm a new user)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the FFT. Maybe yu can try this link:

[FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord)

But you can find on internet many implementation of the algorithm for FFT.